# Trying to use mongodump with remote server heroku using mongolab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodump

In my computer i'm running this command to make a backup of the information of some mongodb database.

```
mongodump -h <hostName>:<port> -d <databes> -u <user> -p <pass> -o direction/where/to/make Backup
```

But gave to me this error:

Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

I try to connect robomongo with the same user, pass, host and databes and it's work fines.

Version of mongo 3.0.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically what I figure from this [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-620)

- The new mongo tool set doesn't work too well with [Unix Domain Socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) . The issue is still open.
- If you're connecting via hostname try using the IP as the link suggests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Nana GodChild Adance helps save my day. I have to downgrade to monogo 2.6.1 and now it's work fine.

Comment: I have tried to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, but still get this error, my comand is: mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --db mydb --username user --password pass /path/to/directory

Comment: I found I have to use an actual ip address, not just 127.0.0.1, in some cases